# Under what conditions the two convex optimization problems are equivalent?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose a convex optimization reads

\begin{alignat}{2}
\text{(P1)} \quad \text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}} \quad & f(x) \\
\text{subject to }\quad &  g_m(x)  \leq 0 \quad m=1,\ldots,M,
\end{alignat}
where $f(x)$ and $\{g_m(x)\}$ are closed convex proper functions.

Forming a Lagrangian of $\text{(P1)}$, we have
\begin{align}
L(x, \{\lambda_m\}) = f(x) + \sum_{m=1}^M \lambda_m \ g_m(x).
\end{align}
where Lagrange multipliers are nonnegative $\{ \lambda_m \geq 0 \}$.

One could also consider KKT conditions. However, I would like to take it from a conceptual level.

Assuming that one has access to optimal Lagrange multipliers $\{ \lambda_m^\star \geq 0 \}$ which maximizes $L(x, \{\lambda_m\})$, then we can say
\begin{align}
\text{(P2)} \quad \text{minimize}_{x} \quad f(x) + \sum_{m=1}^M \lambda_m^\star \ g_m(x).
\end{align}

**Questions**:

1. Would the solution of $\text{(P1)}$, say $x_{\text{(P1)}}^\star$, and $\text{(P2)}$, say $x_{\text{(P2)}}^\star$, be same, $x_{\text{(P1)}}^\star=x_{\text{(P2)}}^\star$, under some conditions?
2. If the answer is yes to the above question, then exactly under what constraint qualification conditions will the solutions be same?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with duality? I'm not sure yet if this is equivalent to ask when does a zero-duality-gap (strong duality) happens.

Comment: I think it doesn't have to do with strong-duality but the part from equation (6) to (8) here might be useful: https://www-cs.stanford.edu/people/davidknowles/lagrangian_duality.pdf as far as I understand how you question is phrased, both problems are equivalent given equation (8). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @FeedbackLooper Thank you for suggestions. This reference is indeed useful.